# How to detect the hash change in an HTTP page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, laravel-5

I have a website with 2 tabs, #edit and #remove. In which, the both tabs are above and below each other. Both tabs have forms, only on its form submit, it focuses to the submitted form, On form submit, I'm making an HTTP request, when the first form is submitted, it will change the url to test.loc/#edit. suppose if a person types #gafdg instead of #edit, he is supposed to move to 404 page. I'm stuck, because it is not an ajax page. Any one have any idea on how to do it.

@Martin I'm asking for ideas only, Not the way to do it..
Don't misunderstand

Comment: Hook to the `onhashchange` event, `$(window).on('hashchange', fn);`

Comment: how about using javascripct to detect location.hash?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It is not an ajax page

Comment: That makes no difference whatsoever: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/e2xejefa/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan On which event I will find the function

Comment: Ok, I've got it, I'm doing it on page load, what if the user type a wrong hash? window onload, nor window onchange hash is working?May I  know if u have any suggestions?